# Recursive "hasCycle" function continues "running" even when a basecase is met

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion, set

Suppose I am given an `array` of `pairs` (where `pair[0]` depends on `pair[1]`). I want to detect whether there is a cycle between any of the pair dependencies.

**Cycle:**
`[[0,1], [1,2], [2, 1]]`

Explanation: There is a cycle between at `1 -> 2` and `2 -> 1`

**Not a Cycle:**
`[[0,1], [1,2], [0, 2]]`

### TLDR;

The problem I am having is... once I have "detected" a loop, I cannot seem to figure out how to "return" it. The callstack coninues executing the "other" children, but I want it to stop.

You can skip to bottom (***The Algorithm***)

### Approach:

1. Create a graph representation of pairs using a `Map` ✅

```js
/**
 * @param { array } [ [intA, intB] ] - Nested array of integers pairs
 * @return { Map } (representing a Graph)
 */
function createGraph(array) {
    const nodes = new Map();
    
    // Create Verticies
    array.map(pair => {
        const aClass = pair[0];
        const bClass = pair[1];
        nodes.set(aClass, []);
        nodes.set(bClass, []);
    })
    
    // Create Edges
    array.map(pair => {
        const aClass = pair[0];
        const bClass = pair[1];
        nodes.get(aClass).push(bClass);
    });
    return nodes;
}
```

And so far, it is working as expected:

```js
// Create Graph
const array = [[0,1], [1,2], [0, 2]];
const graph = createGraph(array);

console.log(graph); 
// Map(3) { 0 => [ 1, 2 ], 1 => [ 2 ], 2 => [] }
```

2. Do a DFS of all the unvisted Nodes (in the `GreySet`) (until we have detect a cycle). ⚠️

I used the 3 Coloured Set approach. I really liked the algorothim and truly wish to implement it. **From my understanding**, it goes as follows.

- `WhiteSet` contains all nodes that have not been touched.
- `GreySet` contains nodes that are currently being explored. Thus, in our DFS, the "parent" will remain in this set.
- `BlackSet` will hold nodes that have already been explored (to the point where there was no cycle).

So... If we explore a child that is in the `BlackSet`, there is no reason for us to explore it any further (it has already been explored and it does not have any cycle anyways). **However**, if we come across a child that is NOT in the WhiteSet AND it exists in the `GreySet`, that means we have a cycle.

Here is my code, I have added the `console.logs` below. **The problem I am having is... once I have "detected" a loop, I cannot seem to figure out how to "return" it.** It continues executing as you will see.

#### ***The Algorithm***:

```js
// Create Graph
const graph = createGraph(array);
console.log(graph); // Looks Good

// Detect Cycle

// Create 3 Sets
const whtSet = new Set(graph.keys()); // Put all the Integer "node values" the set.
const grySet = new Set();
const blkSet = new Set();

const unvisitedValues = whtSet.keys(); // Iterator

while (whtSet.size > 0) {
  const doesItHaveCycle = hasCycle(unvisitedValues.next().value); // Expore any unexplored nodeVal

  console.log('whtSet', whtSet);
  console.log('grySet', grySet);
  console.log('blkSet', blkSet);

  console.log('does it have a cycle', doesItHaveCycle);
}

function hasCycle(nodeVal) {
  // Blackset means it has been compltely explored :)
  if (blkSet.has(nodeVal)) return false;

  // This means we have found a cycle
  if (!whtSet.has(nodeVal) && grySet.has(nodeVal)) return true;

  // Remove it from the whiteSet, into the greySet.
  whtSet.delete(nodeVal);
  grySet.add(nodeVal);

  // Recurse Children
  graph.get(nodeVal).forEach((child) => {
    let doesHaveCycle = hasCycle(child);
    console.log(
      'doesHaveCycle result: ',
      doesHaveCycle,
      'when exploring nodeVal',
      nodeVal,
      'and child',
      child
    );
    if (doesHaveCycle === true) return true; // RETURN THIS PLS lol
  });
  // If above was true, I DO NOT want it to come here, but it still does.
  console.log('if above was true... shouldnt come here');

  // Now, that we have explored all of the children, remove it from Grey Set...
  // Add it to the Black Set
  grySet.delete(nodeVal);
  blkSet.add(nodeVal);
  return false; // IDK
}
```

> Results of `console.log`

```
doesHaveCycle result:  true when exploring nodeVal 2 and child 1
if above was true... shouldnt come here
doesHaveCycle result:  false when exploring nodeVal 1 and child 2
if above was true... shouldnt come here
doesHaveCycle result:  false when exploring nodeVal 0 and child 1
if above was true... shouldnt come here
whtSet Set(0) {}
grySet Set(0) {}
blkSet Set(3) { 2, 1, 0 }
does it have a cycle false
```

I am 100% open revising the code, it is a mess right now. But, I still want to do it the "*3 Colour Set*" way.

For more context, I was trying to take a crack at this cute algorithmic problem called [Course Schedule](https://leetcode.com/problems/course-schedule/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
  // Recurse Children
  graph.get(nodeVal).forEach((child) => {
    let doesHaveCycle = hasCycle(child);
    console.log(
      'doesHaveCycle result: ',
      doesHaveCycle,
      'when exploring nodeVal',
      nodeVal,
      'and child',
      child
    );
    if (doesHaveCycle === true) return true; // RETURN THIS PLS lol
  });
```

The command "RETURN THIS PLS lol" usually works, but this is a special case. `foreach` just calls the callback on each element, and ignores the return value of the callback.

The function you need is called `some`. It calls the given function on each element just like `foreach`, and returns true as soon as one of those calls returns true. (It basically tells if the callback is true for *some* element.) It returns false otherwise.

This is how `some` is used:

```js
  // Recurse Children
  const cycle = graph.get(nodeVal).some((child) => {
    let doesHaveCycle = hasCycle(child);
    console.log(
      'doesHaveCycle result: ',
      doesHaveCycle,
      'when exploring nodeVal',
      nodeVal,
      'and child',
      child
    );
    return doesHaveCycle;
  });
  if (cycle) return true;
  // now this obviously works
  console.log('if above was true... shouldnt come here');
```

You also probably want to break out of the while loop once a cycle is found:

```js
let doesItHaveCycle = false;
while (whtSet.size > 0) {
  doesItHaveCycle = hasCycle(unvisitedValues.next().value); // Expore any unexplored nodeVal
  if (doesItHaveCycle) break;
}
```

Because, we are not doing a full DFS but returning as soon as we see the cycle. This leaves the current node grey and some of its children not-visited. If we wanted to continue after detecting a cycle, we would need to visit all the children, change the current node to black, and **then** return if there is a cycle.